# NeoVim - Strange colours in svn ci

Tags: vim, subversion

I am using neovim as my standard editor on my system.
But when I do a check in, it shows the first two lines in strange colours.

Why is that and how can I change it to normal?

Thanks in advance.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

This *is* normal.
This is the syntax colourization for the `svn` file type (the `gitcommit` filetype has similar).
The red background is telling you that the second line should have been separated from the first line by a blank line.
This is the recommended format (from the `git commit` manual amongst others), and your commit message is not adhering to it.

You can see the command that automatically sets this file type when subversion commit message files are opened, with

```
:autocmd BufRead svn-commit*.tmp
```

(There's an autocommand for git's `COMMIT_EDITMSG` files, similarly.)

Disable the autocommand if you don't want the file type automatically recognized on load.
Disable syntax colourization if you don't want any syntax colourization at all.

But also use the recommended commit message style.

## Further reading

- "[Discussion](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit/#_discussion)". `git-commit`. *git Reference Manual*.  git-scm.com.
- `:help filetype`
- `:help autocmd-remove`
- `:help syntax`